# How to color a div half blue, half yellow?

Tags: html, css, background-color

Please, help me to find the easiest way to achieve this result with just one single div?

```
<div></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can do this:

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3fbc5s63/)

**Snippet Example**

```css
 div{
     width:400px;
     height:350px;
     background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, yellow 50%);
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this code:

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;

background: blue; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, blue 50% , yellow 50%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, blue 50%, yellow 50%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, blue 50%, yellow 50%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50% , yellow 50%); /* Standard syntax */
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background:yellow;
  }

div::after {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  content:"";
  background: blue;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this horizontally?

Comment: @LeonCsergity horizontally its much easier as by default a div acquires all width available in its container. So you just need to adjust height to 50% for each div.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="blue_yellow"></div>
```

css:

```
.blue_yellow {
background: linear-gradient(to left, blue 50%, yellow 50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #leftHalf {
   background-color: blue;
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}

#rightHalf {
   background-color: yellow;
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Try with above CSS code

Comment: and where will you apply that #Id ?

Comment: You can use this inside div tag like css class we use.

Comment: This will not accomplish the task of using just one single div.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try This**
.container{
                height:120px;
                width:120px;
                border-radius:50%;
                background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(183,88,206) 50%, rgb(170,61,200) 50%);
                transform: rotateY(0deg) rotate(45deg);
            }
```

```html
 <html>
     <head>
      <title>Test Box</title>
      <style>
       .container{
        height:120px;
        width:120px;
        border-radius:50%;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(183,88,206) 50%, rgb(170,61,200) 50%);
        transform: rotateY(0deg) rotate(45deg);
       }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div class="container">
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```