# How to color a single div with 3 different colors? (one third blue, one third white, one third red)

Tags: html, css, background-color

I know we can color a div half by half with different colors. For only two colors, the answer is here: 
[How to color a div half blue, half yellow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739270/how-to-color-a-div-half-blue-half-yellow)

But it doesn't work with 3 different colors.

```css
 div{
     width:400px;
     height:220px;
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #002395 33.33%, white 33.33%, #ed2939 33.33%);
    }
```

```html
<div style="font-size:60px; font-family: arial;  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* center horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* center vertically */">FRANCE</div>
```

Please, help me to find the easiest way to achieve this result with just one single div?
This is how the output should look like:

[image]

**I found the answer. Thanks for the answers below.**

In fact, I just had to change the linear-gradient from

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #002395 33.33%, white 33.33%, #ed2939 33.33%);
    }
```

to

```
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #002395, #002395 33.33%, white 33.33%, white 66.66%, #ed2939 66.66%);
```

**And here is the result:**

```css
 div{
     width:400px;
     height:220px;      
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #002395, #002395 33.33%, white 33.33%, white 66.66%, #ed2939 66.66%);
    }
```

```html
<div style="font-size:60px; font-family: arial;  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* center horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* center vertically */">FRANCE</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you just use 3 divs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is done easily using **stops**. The trick is to have **two color stops that are the same**, you can make a solid color instantly change to another solid color.

Check this out:

```css
 div{
     width:400px;
     height:220px;
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #002395, #002395 33.33%, white 33.33%, white 66.66%, #ed2939 66.66%);
    }
```

```html
<div style="font-size:60px; font-family: arial;  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* center horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* center vertically */">FRANCE</div>
```

You can find some more reference on using CSS3 gradients [here](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted

Comment: Can you please explain this? how does it work?
why is this wrong ```background: linear-gradient(to right, #002395 33.33%, white 33.33%, #ed2939 33.33%);```

Comment: You've to use stops here so the solid colors have an immediate transition in the gradient. If you can go through the docs that would explain the answer, specifically [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()#Gradient_with_multi-position_color_stops).

Answer (score 0):

I think applying a gradient color will solve your issue. Try this for your background of the div.

```
div {
    background: #3b9af9;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #3b9af9 0%, #3b9af9 32%, #ffffff 32%, #ffffff 64%, #ef1010 64%, #ef1010 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #3b9af9 0%,#3b9af9 32%,#ffffff 32%,#ffffff 64%,#ef1010 64%,#ef1010 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #3b9af9 0%,#3b9af9 32%,#ffffff 32%,#ffffff 64%,#ef1010 64%,#ef1010 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3b9af9', endColorstr='#ef1010',GradientType=1 );
}
```

You can generate much more gradients of your need from [here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)