# Display three colors in a single DIV Element with Text

Tags: html, css, icons, linear-gradients

How can I display this CSS icon using only a single DIV? I thought of a linear gradient as background, but I couldn't realize it myself until now.

Here you can see that it should work theoretically (of course with different colors).
[How to color a single div with 3 different colors? (one third blue, one third white, one third red)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761927/how-to-color-a-single-div-with-3-different-colors-one-third-blue-one-third-wh)

The first snippet shows how it should look, the second snippet is a very bad trial from me and somehow it does not turn out as it should even the hover effect fails... does anyone can get the whole thing right to work?

```css
body {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
}

.whitepaper {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
}

.blackframe {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 12px 0 12px 0;
  color: white;
  width: 30px;
}

.whitepaper:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="whitepaper">
  <div class="blackframe">URL</div>
</div>

<div class="whitepaper">
  <div class="blackframe">URL</div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
}

.whitepaper {
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, white 10px, black 1px, white);
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
}

.whitepaper:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="whitepaper">URL</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to happen, and what's happening instead? this question is not very clear

Comment: I want the colours to change to the opposite when the hover effect is performed. So what is black should become white and vice versa. And of course the second snippet should look like the first snippet but in a single DIV with a linear gradient background. I hope that was more clear now, otherwise just ask specifically what I should explain.

Comment: Because in the second snippet (so my failed try), the gradient is not separated sharply enough. It is a smooth transition to white, at the bottom it works and is sharp, but at the top the transition is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way linear-gradient works is that the colors and values you list are `stops`, and CSS automatically fills in the space in between and blends it in a gradient. As mentioned in the linked question, the way to get sharp, instant transitions between colors is to create two stops at the same location: one with the old color, and one with the new. That way, there is no "in-between" space to fill with a gradient. You basically just list the starting and ending points for each color as stops, which is what I did here.

The reason your background colors weren't getting overridden on `:hover` is that you used `background-color` under the `:hover` selector, which doesn't override a `linear-gradient`. If you switch it to `background`, as I did, it works fine. I believe this sample works identically to the example you gave. You can adjust the `px` values in the `linear-gradient` if I didn't get them perfect.

```css
body {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
}

.whitepaper {
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, white 12px, black 12px, black 28px, white 28px);
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
}

.whitepaper:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="whitepaper">URL</div>
```

Comment: Wonderfully explained so that even I understood it. And of course it works perfectly! Thanks for the help and have a great evening!

Answer (score 0):

Made some small changes. Changed the linear gradient into something opaque and added background sizing.

You can adjust the black part's size with `background-size`.

```css
body {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
}
.whitepaper {
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 100) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 100) 50%);
  background-size: 100% 50%;
  background-position-y: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
}
.whitepaper:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="whitepaper">URL</div>
```

Comment: This is also a very interesting approach that seems to produce the same result. But since the first post is somewhat smaller and simpler, I will select the first approach as the solution. But anyway thanks for the thought provoking approach that one can realize the things also completely differently than one sometimes thinks. And also to you have a great evening.